# Mac OSX, Safari Push Notification: Generate Push Package from Tokens instead of Certificates

Tags: macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php, safari-push-notifications

As per apple, we can now take advantage of a simpler method of authentication by using tokens instead of certificates when sending push notifications. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222016a)

As per documentation, for generating Push Package we need a Signature file which is PKCS #7 detached signature of the manifest file. This signature file is generated using the Private Key associated with the web push certificate obtained while registering with Apple.

I am not able to figure out how to generate Signature file from the authentication token, instead of web push certificate file.